# How to configure firefox file picker to icon view?

Tags: firefox, filemanager

When I need to upload an image the file dialog in "detailed view" is very painful.
How can I change this?
My os is Lubuntu 14.04

Comment: Please explain exactly what you're trying to do. What are you trying to upload where? Which tools are you using? What is it you don't like about the file selection dialogue that? Can you make a screen shot, possibly with some highlights to the pertaining parts?